# How do I SELECT data from a MySQL table and DELETE everything else?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `logins` (
  `user` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With CRON, every 24 hours, I'm performing a cleanup on this table in a way that I keep only unique logins for every users's IP, i.e. if a certain user logins 5 times from IP X, I keep only the **latest** time he logged in with that IP and delete the remaining 4.

This is my QUERY:

```
DELETE FROM `logins` WHERE (`user`, `time`) NOT IN(
   SELECT `user`, `maxtime`
   FROM(
      SELECT `user`, MAX(`time`) as `maxtime` FROM `logins` GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
   ) as `a`
)
```

This query-subquery way is kind of slow. It takes around 3 seconds to complete.

However, the inner part is extremely quick. If I leave out only the SELECT part, like this:

```
SELECT `user`, MAX(`time`) as `maxtime` FROM `logins` GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
```

It takes less than 0.005 seconds.

So I was wondering: **what if I did the opposite?** Not 'delete all but X', but instead, 'select X, delete all, re-insert X'?

Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
1) SELECT `user`, MAX(`time`) as `maxtime` FROM `logins` GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
/* store this somewhere temporarily */

2) TRUNCATE TABLE `logins`

3) reinsert data from step 1 to `logins`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this to delete all record except the most recent for every combination of user and ip:

```
DELETE l1.*
FROM
  logins l1 INNER JOIN logins l2
  ON l1.user=l2.user
     AND l1.ip=l2.ip
     AND l1.time<l2.time
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60047/1).

Comment: I don't think this will produce the desired result. I want to keep all recent logins per user per IP, not only per user. If you login from 50 IPs, I need 50 entries for your user.

Answer (score 2):

Use another (temporary or not) table to insert the data you want to keep. Truncate. Then insert it back...

```
INSERT INTO LoginsTemp 
SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE ...; 

TRUNCATE Logins; 

INSERT INTO Logins 
SELECT * FROM LoginsTemp;
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Will these 3 queries ran together as you show in your example lock the table for the whole duration/time? I.E. what happens if any user logins to the system after the first query ran and before the table is truncated? Will I lose their data?

Comment: you can create a transaction around them to prevent concurrency issues

Comment: To avoid a second reload, you could do an atomic rename:  rename table Logins to LoginsOld, LoginsTemp to Logs;